# Is there a way to switch the output sound of the beep program to the normal loud speaker instead of beeper?

Tags: command-line, drivers, audio

I installed the [`beep` tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/beep.1.html) (from normal rep) on my ubuntu 18.04

After `modprobe pcspkr` everything was OK. But it has been heard from my very small beeper from the PC's box only.
Is there a way to hear it from normal music loud speaker as like any mp3, youtube etc?

I note the `echo -e '\007'` bell command from my shell is heard from normal music loud speaker it is very good for me.

Using of `-e` option of beep didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

The `beep` tool is explicitly designed to use the beeper only.

The `echo -e '\007'` uses whatever bell effect your terminal emulator is configured to do: on the text-mode console, it typically uses the beeper. In a GUI desktop terminal window, the terminal emulator might have its own configurable beep sound, or it might use the desktop environment's default beep effect, which is usually configurable in the sound settings of the desktop environment.

Having said that, it is sometimes possible to redirect the beeper's sound into the speakers. In order to do that, you need an integrated sound chip (as most modern systems have), with a specific ability to reroute the beeper sound (which is included in some but not all sound chips). To enable that feature in Linux, you'll need to access the sound mixer functions of the actual sound card, instead of the simplified version that you'll get normally if your system includes the PulseAudio subsystem.

For example, if you use the `alsamixer` command with no options in a PulseAudio-enabled system, you may see the volume control of PulseAudio only. But if you explicitly specify the sound card to use with e.g. `alsamixer -c 0` to specify the first sound card/chip of the system, you'll get the full audio mixer settings.

If the list of available sound channels includes "Beep", "Digital Beep" or something like that, it would be the PC beeper redirection channel. It might be just an on/off switch setting, or an adjustable level setting, or both. If you enable/unmute the channel, the beeper's signal should be redirected to the sound chip and output through the normal speakers.

Note: if your system has this feature and you decide to use it, check the volume level of the beep *before* you reboot the system. If you enable the redirection and set it to full volume, the standard beep at reboot time may come through the speakers and get amplified to unexpected loudness.

(Yes, this happened to me once. Apparently the sound chip is not always fully reset at reboot, at least not until the OS startup has proceeded to load the sound drivers again.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I have beep column in alsamixer,
but nothing effect if I changed the level, but e.g.: Master column worked well.
I copied to gdrv 3 pictures from my alasmixer menu and my lshw output,
if you could have more idea.  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dXHAC85xP9AcEkMWrk2PnKoYknIS1vUc?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you unmute the beep channel first, by selecting the channel in `alsamixer` and pressing the M key so that the `MM` at the bottom of the channel level bar turns into `OO`? In your pictures, the beep channel is still muted (`MM`).

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it you can see on fourth jpg on the above link, but the e.g.: `beep -f600` only sounds on the beeper not on the loudspeaker.

Comment: Then it probably means your motherboard’s manufacturer did not wire it in although the sound chip has the capability for it, unfortunately.